# Characters in inspector is not visible

Tags: unity-game-engine

unity2022.2.0b TMP3.2.0-pre.4

I recently updated my project from 2019LTS.
After that, characters entered in "string" and "textarea" in the inspector are not displayed.

Now, I get one of the following error messages:
1: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2: MissingReferenceException: The variable m_AtlasTextures of FontAsset doesn't exist anymore.

My language is Japanese.
I know I get similar errors when the TMP textures are full, but I don't use TMP for my project.
It can be fixed by restarting Unity, but it is troublesome because it happens frequently. Anyone know how to solve this?

[images of the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cujOq.png)

Here is the log.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.FontAsset.SetupNewAtlasTexture () (at <d848a5f0d57c4e96b3f27c1dd5805d00>:0)
UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.FontAsset.TryAddCharacterInternal (System.UInt32 unicode, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.Character& character, System.Boolean shouldGetFontFeatures) (at <d848a5f0d57c4e96b3f27c1dd5805d00>:0)
UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.FontAssetUtilities.GetCharacterFromFontAsset_Internal (System.UInt32 unicode, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.FontAsset sourceFontAsset, System.Boolean includeFallbacks, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.FontStyles fontStyle, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextFontWeight fontWeight, System.Boolean& isAlternativeTypeface) (at <d848a5f0d57c4e96b3f27c1dd5805d00>:0)
UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.FontAssetUtilities.GetCharacterFromFontAsset_Internal (System.UInt32 unicode, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.FontAsset sourceFontAsset, System.Boolean includeFallbacks, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.FontStyles fontStyle, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextFontWeight fontWeight, System.Boolean& isAlternativeTypeface) (at <d848a5f0d57c4e96b3f27c1dd5805d00>:0)
UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.FontAssetUtilities.GetCharacterFromFontAssets (System.UInt32 unicode, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.FontAsset sourceFontAsset, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] fontAssets, System.Boolean includeFallbacks, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.FontStyles fontStyle, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextFontWeight fontWeight, System.Boolean& isAlternativeTypeface) (at <d848a5f0d57c4e96b3f27c1dd5805d00>:0)
UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextGenerator.GetTextElement (UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextGenerationSettings generationSettings, System.UInt32 unicode, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.FontAsset fontAsset, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.FontStyles fontStyle, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextFontWeight fontWeight, System.Boolean& isUsingAlternativeTypeface) (at <d848a5f0d57c4e96b3f27c1dd5805d00>:0)
UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextGenerator.SetArraySizes (UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextProcessingElement[] textProcessingArray, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextGenerationSettings generationSettings, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextInfo textInfo) (at <d848a5f0d57c4e96b3f27c1dd5805d00>:0)
UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextGenerator.Prepare (UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextGenerationSettings generationSettings, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextInfo textInfo) (at <d848a5f0d57c4e96b3f27c1dd5805d00>:0)
UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextGenerator.GetPreferredValues (UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextGenerationSettings settings, UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextInfo textInfo) (at <d848a5f0d57c4e96b3f27c1dd5805d00>:0)
UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextHandle.UpdatePreferredValues (UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextGenerationSettings tgs) (at <d848a5f0d57c4e96b3f27c1dd5805d00>:0)
UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextHandle.ComputeTextWidth (UnityEngine.TextCore.Text.TextGenerationSettings tgs) (at <d848a5f0d57c4e96b3f27c1dd5805d00>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UITKTextHandle.ComputeTextWidth (System.String textToMeasure, System.Boolean wordWrap, System.Single width, System.Single height) (at <2c62f5a99353486389ce268a5295ac09>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.TextUtilities.MeasureVisualElementTextSize (UnityEngine.UIElements.TextElement te, System.String textToMeasure, System.Single width, UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement+MeasureMode widthMode, System.Single height, UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement+MeasureMode heightMode) (at <2c62f5a99353486389ce268a5295ac09>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.TextElement.MeasureTextSize (System.String textToMeasure, System.Single width, UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement+MeasureMode widthMode, System.Single height, UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement+MeasureMode heightMode) (at <2c62f5a99353486389ce268a5295ac09>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.TextElement.DoMeasure (System.Single desiredWidth, UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement+MeasureMode widthMode, System.Single desiredHeight, UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement+MeasureMode heightMode) (at <2c62f5a99353486389ce268a5295ac09>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement.Measure (UnityEngine.Yoga.YogaNode node, System.Single width, UnityEngine.Yoga.YogaMeasureMode widthMode, System.Single height, UnityEngine.Yoga.YogaMeasureMode heightMode) (at <2c62f5a99353486389ce268a5295ac09>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement.<AssignMeasureFunction>b__423_0 (UnityEngine.Yoga.YogaNode node, System.Single f, UnityEngine.Yoga.YogaMeasureMode mode, System.Single f1, UnityEngine.Yoga.YogaMeasureMode heightMode) (at <2c62f5a99353486389ce268a5295ac09>:0)
UnityEngine.Yoga.YogaNode.MeasureInternal (UnityEngine.Yoga.YogaNode node, System.Single width, UnityEngine.Yoga.YogaMeasureMode widthMode, System.Single height, UnityEngine.Yoga.YogaMeasureMode heightMode) (at <2c62f5a99353486389ce268a5295ac09>:0)
UnityEngine.Yoga.Native.YGNodeMeasureInvoke (UnityEngine.Yoga.YogaNode node, System.Single width, UnityEngine.Yoga.YogaMeasureMode widthMode, System.Single height, UnityEngine.Yoga.YogaMeasureMode heightMode, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <2c62f5a99353486389ce268a5295ac09>:0)
UnityEditor.InspectorWindow:RedrawFromNative()
```

Comment: You mentioned you don't use TMP for your project, but you provided a version for it. Is it installed?

Comment: TMP was originally included in unity. I thought it was a problem with the version of TMP, so I updated to the latest version, but it didn't solve the problem. My game does not use TMP.

Comment: I realize now that the error traceback is the default unity UI, so TMP doesn’t have anything to do with it. Can you edit the post to include some images of the inspector view for the ui elements and your script?

Comment: I have attached the image. At first, characters are displayed, but an error occurs during work, and after that only Japanese characters are not displayed.

Comment: The only suggestion I can make is to use TMP for your ui. I’ve heard they have better support overall and it is pretty easy to transfer. Unity’s default ui systems kinda suck and they recommend TMP.

Comment: "Project Settings > Editor > Inspector > Use IMGUI Default Inspector" fixed it.